# ¿Cómo colocar saltos de línea en un JTextArea en Java?

Tags: java, java-swing

tengo un editor de texto en java :v en este puedes abrir y guardar archivos colocando la ruta del archivo mas el formato... pero cuando guardas un archivo los saltos de lineas que colocas no se guardan aquí una parte de mi código cuando preciosas el botón de guardar

```js
        String archivo=new String(rutas.getText());//aqui se guarda en una variable el texto de la ruta    
        String archivo2=new String(editor.getText());//aqui se optiene el texto que tiene el editor    
        try {
            PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(archivo);
            String saltos = editor.getText().replace("\n", "\r\n");
            writer.println(archivo2);
            
            writer.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

GRACIAS por la ayuda

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iniciemos por entender que significa un Salto de linea [Wikipedia en Ingles sobre "new line"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) o si no puedes entender bien el ingles [Wikipedia en español sobre "new line"](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salto_de_l%C3%ADnea) (el link en español eso es es muy pobre a lo cual minimo suguiero usar google translate en la version en ingles...) 
en sintesis existen varias formas de demostrar una nueva linea dependiendo del applicativo y/o Systema Operativo. los mas comunes son:

Unix like:`'\n'`

Windows & DOS: `'\r'+'\n'`

`'\r'`– Macs (OS 9 y anteriores)

donde `'\n'` significa "Line Feed" y `'\r'` Carriage return

con lo anterior claro, recordemos que Java es Independiente de la plataforma y puede utilizar o no el mismo caracter. en los elementos como el JTextArea los saltos de linea por defecto son representados como `'\n'`

por tanto cuando usas `editor.getText()` este retorna in String. que muy probablemente sus lineas son separadas por `'\n'` para guardar el String a un archivo y conservar las "nuevas lineas" **con el mismo formato del systema Operativo** en donde se ejecuta la applicacion se debe realizar una de las siguientes acciones:

A:

```
String salto = System.lineSeparator(); //java 6 para atras se utiliza: System.getProperty("line.separator");
String towrite= editor.getText().replace("\n",salto);
writer.println(towrite);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

B:

```
String salto = System.lineSeparator(); //java 6 para atras se utiliza: System.getProperty("line.separator");
editor.getDocument().putProperty(DefaultEditorKit.EndOfLineStringProperty, salto);
editor.write(writer);
writer.flush();
writer.close();
```

mas sobre este metodo ver [este link](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/02/07/text-and-new-lines/)

particularmente en tu codigo el problema que tienes es el siguiente:

`new String()` es redundante Y ademas un gasto de memoria innesesario los String en java son Immutables!

> ```
>    String archivo=new String(rutas.getText());
> ```

debe ser

```
    String archivo=rutas.getText();
```

esta linea esta de mas y/o la variable esta mal nombrada

> ```
>     String archivo2=new String(editor.getText());//aqui se optiene el texto que tiene el editor
> ```

modificarlo a algo mas significativo:

```
String texto_editor= editor.getText();
```

Y el mayor offensor! `saltos` es el texto que remplazo `'\n'` por `"\r\n"` **pero no se hace nada con el** por que la siguiente linea lo que hace es **guardar archivo2** que se hace con la variable `saltos`

> ```
>         String saltos = editor.getText().replace("\n", "\r\n");
>         writer.println(archivo2);
>         ...
>     }
> ```

recuerda, los String son immutables. si lee un texto del UI y lo modifica, este no se refleja en el UI, debe re ingresar el texto, y aun si ese fuera el caso `archivo2` **no** es una referencia al texto de `editor` por tanto igual esta mal.

Comment: Gracias Eres muy bueno en esto :v