# Extraer String, con saltos de linea ,de un JTextArea

Tags: java-swing

Tengo un JTextArea configurado con saltos de linea automático y para que no te recorte una palabra al dar el salto:

```
textArea.setLineWrap(true);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
```

Funciona todo bien, realiza los saltos de linea perfectamente, pero el problema es al extraer el **String** del JTextArea, ya que me devuelve el texto todo seguido **sin saltos de linea**.

Así lo obtengo y lo muestro:

```
String strTextArea =textArea.getText();
System.out.println(strTextArea);
```

También probé copiar linea por linea con **split("\n")**:

```
String [] lineas =textArea.getText().split("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < lineas.length; i++) {
  System.out.println("linea "+i+": "+lineas[i]);
}
```

y me devuelve el **array** con **un solo elemento** que contiene el texto, o sea sin saltos de linea.
Pareciera ser que el **JTextArea** ejecuta y muestra los saltos de linea mientras se esté usando dicho componente, pero al extraer o copiar el texto contenido se pierden los saltos de linea.

Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: `\n` no funciona para todas las plataformas, te recomiendo remplazarlo por la propiedad de la clase System correspondiente o especificar el sistrema operativo en tu pregunta.

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cómo colocar saltos de línea en un JTextArea en Java?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/216732/c%c3%b3mo-colocar-saltos-de-l%c3%adnea-en-un-jtextarea-en-java)

Comment: Estoy usando Windows, cómo se usa esa propiedad?

Comment: Es que no está metiendo saltos de línea cuando no cabe una línea entera. Es algo que gestiona Android, pero no modifica el texto introducido. Con lo que al pedir que te lo retorne así, con `getText`, te devuelve todo como está, sin saltos de línea. Tendrías que preguntar cuantas líneas hay e ir pidiéndoselas. Tienes ejemplos a montones en google.

Comment: Me sugerieron esta pregunta similar: https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/216732/116640, aunque no es muy similar, y tampoco funcionó. No necesito escribir un archivo, solo copiar el texto del JTextArea y pasarselo a un JOptionPane conservando los saltos de linea

Comment: @SuperG280 entonces digamos que hay que crear los saltos manualmente, lo puedo hacer con subString(), pero qué se hace para que no se corte una palabra?

Comment: No, con las funciones de la clase JTextArea. [Mira este enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10253409/how-to-read-line-by-line-from-a-text-area)